# Listview control in vbnet

Tags: vb.net, listview

this question might be very simple to you guys. I am using a listview for my log details and i'm wondering on how can i set the focus to the last item on my listview and the scrollbar should be on the last portion of the listview. i can currently set the focus to the last item by this code: **lvSample.Items((lvSample.Items.count-1)).Selected = True** but the scrollbar is still on topmost portion. i need help guys. thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
 lvSample.Items(lvSample.Items.count-1).EnsureVisible()
```